# Source of a quote about the value of mitzvot involving pain

Tags: sources-mekorot, mitzvah, reward-punishment, talmud-yerushalmi, suffering

This quote is attributed to the Yerushalmi:

> One mitzvah involving pain is worth a hundred mitzvot that do not.

Do you have the exact reference?  Is this the only place this thought is expressed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an Avos D'Reb Nosson 3:6:

ישמעאל ברבי יוסי אומר, אם למדת תורה בילדותך, אל תאמר איני לומד בזקנותי. אלא למוד תורה, כי אינך יודע איזה יכשר. אם למדת תורה בשעת העושר, אל תשוב לך בשעת העוני. אם למדת תורה בשעת שביעה, אל תשוב לך בשעת רעבה. אם למדת תורה בשעת הריוח, אל תשוב לך בשעת הדחק. **לפי שטוב לו לאדם דבר אחד בצער ממאה בריוח**. שנאמר, (קהלת יא) "בבקר זרע את זרעך ולערב אל תנח ידך".

Comment: Thanks! Not in the Yerushalmi?